# color between lines, depending which one is above

Tags: plot, colors, line, fill, between

The fill function does work very well to fill the space between my 2 plots with color.
But now I want to go one step further and want to color, depending on which line is above.
So for example when p1 is above p2 the color between should be green, if p2 is above p1 the color between should be red. How can I do this?

```
p1 = plot(open)
p2 = plot(close)
fill(p1, p2, color = color.new(color.green, 90))
```

use the fill function but need to combine it